# Different wallpaper for each homescreen?

Tags: home-screen, nexus-7, wallpaper, aokp

I'd like to be able to have a different wallpaper for each homescreen. I found a live wallpaper that lets you do this. 
Is there a more efficient/less cumbersome way?

Comment: The homescreen pages aren't separate desktops.  I don't think there's anything you can do, plus I don't think it should be particularly inefficient or cumbersome to use a live wallpaper.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the default Android launcher does NOT allow you to do this. However, there are some launchers available on Play Store which let you do this. [Regina 3D Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemustech.regina) is one of them.

The other option I see is what you are already doing, using a live wallpaper like [MultiPicture Live Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tamanegi.wallpaper.multipicture).

(I have mentioned some popular apps to do this, there are alternatives available, you can search on Play store.)